# Split string by arithmetic operators

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string `"str1+str2-str3*str4"`.

I want to split it so I get an array

`['str1','+','str2','-','str3','*','str4']`.

Could someone help provide a solution?

Comment: Have you tried solving this problem yourself yet?

Comment: Please don't tag something Angular unless the code actually relates to the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If JS split lets capture groups become elements, then this should work

`/([-+*\/])/`

if not, I suggest using a regular find all type thing
using this

`/([-+*\/]|[^-+*\/]+)/`

otherwise, I'll just delete this.